# How to use create table for nested classes in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I'm new to MySQL and I want to connect my java spring back-end to a MySQL DB. I am using a JDBC driver for that, but I don't know how to convert my nested classes to tables in the database.

Suppose I have a Course class which some of its fields contain another class, for example my course class is like this:

```
public class Course{

    private String code;
    private String classCode;
    private String name;
    private int units;
    private String type;
    private String instructor;
    private int capacity;
    private List<String> prerequisites = new ArrayList<>();
    private ClassTime classTime;
    private ExamTime examTime;
    private int signedUp;
    private List<Student> waitingList;
}
```

so for instance classTime and examTime has type of another class which itself contains some other fields, for example here is ClassTime class:

```
public class ClassTime {
    private List<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
    private String time;
}
```

or waitingList is a list of Students.

So I want to use create table:

```
create table COURSES (
    code tinytext not null,
    classCode tinytext not null,
    name tinytext not null,
    units int not null,
    type enum('Asli', 'Paaye', 'Takhasosi', 'Umumi') not null,
    instructor tinytext not null,
    capacity int not null,
    primary key(code, classCode),
 );
```

I don't know how to define fields like classTime and waitingList.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: If you already in Spring, try to use JPA and annotations. This will automate whole the process

Comment: @DanielZ. thank you for responsing, I'm not allowed to use JPA and Hibernate , so I have to handle the whole proccess manually. could you guide me with this consideration?

Answer (score 0):

The classical SQL way to represent relations is to create KEYs.

When you have relation **may-to-one** (like book-to-publisher), you create the second table (publisher) and then ***foreign key*** in 1st table (book) pointing to second table(author).

If relation is **many-to-many** (like book-to-authors), you create second table (author) and additional ***join table*** (book_author), having two **foreign keys** pointing to 1st (book) and 2nd (author).

The JPA creates all these constraints automatically. If you are not allowed to use JPA, it is your responsibility to create all the staff.

Any case, when you use JDBC directly, Spring provides useful **JdbcTemplate**, which significantly simplifies your work with SQL queries and related data transformations. You can see examples here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate